# Request first result in JSON API output

Tags: javascript, json, api

My API call

```
var UserAdminget = {
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
"id": Math.round(Math.random() * (999999 - 100000) + 100000),
"method": "UserAdmin.get",
"params": {
        "api_key": api,
        "user_id": user_id,
    }};
```

The JSON output I get is

```
{"result":{"6494093":{"username":"ROJO8399","forum_post_count":"84","forum_votes":"15","forum_up_votes":"15","forum_down_votes":"0","lastseen":"1430338238","datejoined":"1392351660","points_total":"1","points_day":"0","points_week":"0","points_month":"1","points_forum":"0","points_purchase":"0","points_other":"1","points_spent":"0","points_decayed":"0","points_adjusted":"0"}},"id":"55413ddd897b5","jsonrpc":"2.0"}
```

I'm trying to get the "forum_post_count" as a variable. I've tried response.result.6494093.forum_post_count and the numbers don't work. I've tried response.result[0].forum_post_count and I get undefined. Also, the UserID is as a variable because I get it from the URL of the page. It's "user_id".

EDIT:
response.result.6494093.forum_post_count says "unexpected number".
response.result[0].forum_post_count says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'forum_post_count' of undefined"

var user_id = "6494093";
response.result.user_id.forum_post_count is "undefined" too.

(THE API I'M WORKING WITH IS THE ENJIN API - http://enjin.com/api )

Comment: Did you try running the string through `JSON.parse` first ?

Comment: Oh, and `response.result['6494093'].forum_post_count`

Answer (score 0):

```
resp = {"result":
         {"6494093":
           {"username":"ROJO8399",
            "forum_post_count":"84",
            "forum_votes":"15",
            "forum_up_votes":"15",
            "forum_down_votes":"0",
            "lastseen":"1430338238",
            "datejoined":"1392351660",
            "points_total":"1",
            "points_day":"0",
            "points_week":"0",
            "points_month":"1",
            "points_forum":"0",
            "points_purchase":"0",
            "points_other":"1",
            "points_spent":"0",
            "points_decayed":"0",
            "points_adjusted":"0"
           }
         },
         "id":"55413ddd897b5",
         "jsonrpc":"2.0"
       }

var forum_post_count = resp['result']['6494093']['forum_post_count']
```